# Getting error while inserting into database in mule flow

Tags: json

Very new to mule esb. I am trying to retrive json response from http request connector and then inserting it into db. Not sure why I am not able to fetch the values when I am  inserting it into DB.

Getting the following error while inserting into database:

> Execution of the expression
>   "message.payload.Data.MissingItems.Institution" failed.
>   (org.mule.api.expression.ExpressionRuntimeException).

My conf file

[image]

Comment: Please run your application in debug mode with debug point set on "JSON to Object transformer".This will let you know if payload is getting properly transformed from JSON to HashMap.If possible please paste the screen shot that will help us get to the root of issue.Just need to check the format of transformed data

Comment: Thanks for response mahesh.

Answer (score 0):

Put a debugger before foreach and inside foreach and see how the values are being stored inside the map.Run the application in debug mode and see the structure of the payload using mule expression language.You can find out the option inside the debugger.There you can put #[message.payload] or #[message.payload.Data] or #[message.payload.Data.MissingItems] to check the structure of the message.It will also help you to understand if the issue is related to transformation or anything else.

Comment: Thanku all... i did mistake with xpath while inserting into db... after for each the  xpath was like  this because i was iterating the loop: Insert into portal.dbo.eportalMigrationLog(Institution,migrationType,identifier,requestNo,errCode,errMessage,createdDate) values(#[message.payload.Institution],#[message.payload.ctcAssetTag],123,#[message.payload.ibmAssetTag],#[message.payload.SerialNo],#[message.payload.Description],CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)